# Connecting rod bearing torque specs 2003 Ford Mustang

Tags: ford, mustang, torque

Anyone know any good websites to check for torque specs? I have looked on library.alldatapro and google, and I couldnt find it. Are there any reliable websites out there that anyone knows with car information like this?

Comment: Which engine? V6 (3.8 or 3.9), V8 4.6 (SOHC or DOHC or Supercharged). Five different engines which were used that year. I know it would make a huge difference on the Cobra (SC) engine as Ford used aftermarket parts in the SC engine for 2003 & 2004.

Comment: I'm going to go with the 3.8, since that's what you have in your other questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to have a set of manuals that had all of this info but, for reasons I won't get into, I don't have them at this time.  But I remember tightening end caps on a 2001 v6 3.8l several years ago, if that's what you have.  Three step process to tighten end cap bolts should go as follows:

Tighten to 18 ft. lbs.
Then tighten to 33 ft. lbs.
Lastly, tighten another 105 degrees.

It's my opinion that the bolts should be new.  Threads should be lubed (oil or something). Oh, and just to clarify, this info is for standard size (not under or oversized).  Thanks @Ben for confirmation.

Comment: specs are basically the same between the two years. the only difference is SI specifies 105 degree final tightening.

Comment: @Ben- So you think I'm safe removing the disclaimer?

Comment: yah, just modify the 40-120 to 105 degrees the rest is the same for 03 3.8l. three steps 18/33/105.

Comment: Really?  I remember my manual specifically expressing this range of final tightening.  105 would, of course, work fine within that range but why do you say 105 in particular?

Comment: it's just what SI provides as specs in 01/02 they specify a range but in 03 it changes to only 105.

Comment: Good enough for me.  Thx @Ben.

Comment: @Ben - Aren't these torque-to-yield (T2Y) bolts? Having them in the rod caps seems really strange to me, but many sources I saw online were showing them as such. If so, they'd need to be replaced. You cannot reuse T2Y bolts. I would ***absolutely*** not try to reuse them on connecting rod caps, that's for sure!!